# How to save model/checkpoints after certain epoch, save best only

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max',save_frequency=1)
```

basically how to periodically check if the new check val_loss is better and save the checkpoint after every epoch but only after at least 100 epoch?

so the model will save the 100th epoch weight and now check the val_loss of any subsequent epoch

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow provides option to save checkpoints based on epoch number.

```
# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

# Train the model with the new callback
model.fit(train_images, 
          train_labels,  
          epochs=100,
          validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
          callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

Save checkpoints based on metrics such val_loss, accuracy by defining specified value in custom callback. For more details take look at [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_checkpoints_during_training). Thanks!

Comment: if training stops at 50th epochs, how to save add 50th epoch into checkpoint_path?

Comment: You use custom callback to save the checkpoints based on your requirement. Thanks!